# mclapply in R: object 'X' not found

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, mclapply

I'm trying to use mclapply from the parallel package (on a Mac) and am running into an issue. I've defined a function edge.loop as:

```
edge.loop <- function(index) {
   hw.edge <- E(G)[HW.edges][index]
   apath <- E(G)$emig.route[[hw.edge]]
   short.cut <- apath[is.in.graph(G, apath, what="edges")]
   Edata <- get.data.frame(G, what="edges")
   lag.surv <- 1; # initialize
   x.surv <- 1
   result_list <- vector("list",length(short.cut))
   for (x in short.cut) {
      if ( E(G)[x]$cum.path.surv == -1 ) {
        if ( E(G)[x]$int.dam.type!=0 ) {
          x.surv <- 0
          if (E(G)[x]$up.passage==1) {
            x.surv <- lag.surv*E(G)[x]$Sentrain*S.Impinge 
          }
          result_list[x] <- x.surv
          lag.surv <- x.surv                                                                          
        }         
      } 
      else lag.surv <- E(G)[x]$cum.path.surv
    }    
  return(list("short.cut" = short.cut, "x.surv" = result_list))
}
```

When I call this function as

```
x <- edge.loop(1)
```

it works just fine, but if I try

```
x <- lapply(1:2, edge.loop)
```

or

```
x <- mclapply(1:2, edge.loop)
```

I get an error reading

```
Error during wrapup: object 'X' not found.
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I run it, I get: Error in edge.loop(1) : could not find function "E"

Comment: This function exists within another function that uses the igraph package. I think I figured out the problem regardless... I needed to specify that index is an integer, not a double. Thanks for looking into this though!